# Let $ f $ be a continuous function in $ [a, b] $ show that.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, continuity

Let $ f $ be a continuous function in $ [a, b] $ and $ \displaystyle \int_{a} ^ {b} f (t) dt \neq0 $. Prove that at any point $ k \in (0,1) $ there exists a number $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ \displaystyle \int_{a} ^ {c} f (t) dt = k \int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt $.

I had the intention of solving it by means of the mean value theorem, for example considering that,
$$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt$$
but I have a problem, because I get that,
$$\int_{a}^{c}f(t)dt=\frac{1}{(b-a)f(c)}\left[\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt\right]^{2}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Then $F(a)=0$ and $F(b)=\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Since $k\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ lies between $F(a)$ and $F(b)$, there must be a $c\in(a,b)$ such that$$F(c)\left(=\int_a^cf(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)=k\int_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm dt,$$by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Excuse a question, how can I know that $ k \in (0,1) $ because, it's supposed to have an average interpretation,

Comment: I don't understand this comment. In your question, it was *assumed* that $k\in(0,1)$ and I used that assumption.